# How do I get intermediate values of VQE algorithm using callback?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, qiskit, vqe

I'm new to using Qiskit Aqua, and I'm trying to get the intermediate values in the VQE algorithm to study the convergence. [The documentation](https://qiskit.aqua.algorithms.adaptive.VQE.html) mentions an internal callback function, but I can't figure out how to use it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this tutorial notebook https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-community-tutorials/blob/master/aqua/vqe_convergence.ipynb which should answer what you need

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed

Comment: I had the same question, and found this answer is really useful. I have a followed up question. How can I get the parameters at each intermediate step? I tried to modify "store_intermediate_result" function by adding "para.append( parameters )". However, it seems like only the very last set of parameters are saved. Any ideas?